# Unable to test the component containing SVG using react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, svg, jestjs

This is the  error which I am encountering while I am trying to test my component which contains one of the SVG inbuilt function

> TypeError: circle.getPointAtLength is not a function

```
      49 |         let sdo = circle.getAttribute("stroke-dashoffset")
      50 |         let arcpos = sda - sdo
    > 51 |         let points = circle.getPointAtLength(arcpos)
         |                             ^
      52 |         let thumb = document.getElementById("thumb" + key)
      53 |         thumb.setAttribute("cx", points.x)
      54 |         thumb.setAttribute("cy", points.y)
```

Comment: getPointAtLength works with <path>, not with <circle>

Comment: For <circle> you can simply calculate any point by center, radius, and angle

Comment: What's `circle` object? Include the code